# How to make simple Audio Player in React Native

Tags: react-native, audio, podcast

I am working on React-Native application. I have to play Audio using URL(podcast) source.

The UI should be like following.

[image]

I have tried react-native-video library, But, The UI is different.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video

Is there any other library available to achieve this?

I have to show Progressbar(Slider), Play/Pause/Stop, Title. And I have to play audio in background state too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library,
it has everything like Play audio files, stream audio from URL
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player

Comment: This is not showing any controls and progressbar too. Nothing UI showing, It is just playing audio?

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-track-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player) provides almost all features a audio player, you can also use it to play audio in background, used it for [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epicgeniusllc.caliente96) app

Comment: This player getting issues on bother iOS and Android while installing application due to version issues.

Comment: try the [example app](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/tree/dev/example)

Comment: Did you got my point, It is supporting from OS version minimum 24 in Android, But, Our project is supporting minimum version is 16 in Android, Same iOS also not able to install pod due to version support.